Wait, ASCII was 128 characters all along?
Challenge
In this challenge, you have to take a nonnegative integer as input, convert it into base-128 bytes (0 → 0x00, 127 → 0x7F, 5,732 → 0x2C 0x64, etc.), and output whether the result only uses printable ASCII (0x20 to 0x7E inclusive).
Test cases
0 --> false (␀)
9 --> false (␉)
10 --> false (␊)
13 --> false (␍)
27 --> false (␛)
32 --> true (␠)
59 --> true (;)
87 --> true (W)
126 --> true (~)
127 --> false (␡)
128 --> false (␁␀)
300 --> false (␂,)
2201 --> false (␑␙)
5732 --> true (,d)
134711010 --> false (@␞␍b)
157061374 --> true (Jr!~)
157061375 --> false (Jr!␡)

Specifications

The maximum input you will receive is 4,294,967,295.
You may use a function or a full program.
Standard loopholes, I/O methods, and decision-problem I/O methods apply.

Scoring
This is code-golf, so fewest bytes wins.

at present all test cases have the critical character at the end, so 127>number%128>31 passes all those tests without actually answering the challenge. can you provide test cases where the last character is printable but an earlier one isn't?

I added 134711010, but test case 300 is already "␂,", so...

my bad, but thank you for the longer one.

By default, decision problems allow outputting truthy / falsy values. Can you confirm that this is accepted (and if so edit that into the challenge text)?

That was the second bullet point in Specifications, so yes, it is accepted.

@squareroot12621 truthy/falsy may be eg. nonzero vs zero, which may not meet the "consistent, distinct values" from the second bullet point.

Having 0 --> false seems like an exceptional edge case here, since it should convert to the empty string which vacuously has no unprintable characters.

@xnor Since the challenge asks convert the input into base-128 [...] and output whether the result only uses printable ASCII (0x20 to 0x7E inclusive), 0 --> false seems totally fine to me. I don't see that as an edge case at all. The challenge doesn't mention converting to strings

I assume inputs 9 and 10 should also return false (i.e. tabs and line feeds should not be considered printable). Those might be worth adding as test cases.

@xnor arguably 0 would be a string with just a null byte (0x00), rather than an empty string. And the null byte isn't printable, so it makes sense to have false.

I agree with @xnor, it is very ambiguous. Any input might or might not have any null characters at the end, but the test cases imply that they don't (otherwise, the challenge is pointless). So then why should the 0 input be treated differently? Might as well be an empty string.

@IlmariKaronen: 0x09 and 0x0A aren't in the range 0x20 to 0x7E, so they aren't printable.

@xnor, Jitse: It's not like converting 0 to a different base makes it disappear or something...

@squareroot12621 It's not that changing base makes it disappear, it's that the base-10 representation is also the empty string/list, except by convention we've agreed to write it with an extra (leading) zero because it would be too hard to communicate the number by writing nothing. See this on Meta.

@squareroot12621: Some built-in "is this printable ASCII" tests might consider 0x9 and 0xA (and possibly 0xD) to be printable, though, since they're commonly used in ASCII text files. That's why I suggested adding them as test cases.

@IlmariKaronen: Alright, I added 9 (tab) and 10 (LF), as well as 13 (CR) for good measure.

JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes
Very similar to Jitse's answer.
Returns 0 for printable or true for non-printable.
f=n=>-~n%128<33||(n>>=7)&&f(n)

Try it online!

JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes
-2 thanks to @tsh
Returns 0 for printable / truthy for non-printable.
f=n=>-~n%128<33||f(n>>=7)*n

Try it online!

f=n=>-~n%128<33||f(n>>=7)*n (27)

Jelly, 7 bytes
bØ⁷ỌḟØṖ

Try It Online!
bØ⁷ỌḟØṖ    main link
b          convert to base
 Ø⁷                        128
   Ọ       convert to characters
    ḟ      filter to remove
     ØṖ    printable ASCII

If anything is left after the filter (i.e. the return value is a non-empty list), then it's the false case. If the filter removes everything (i.e. the return value is an empty list), then it's the true case. The footer uses Ṇ (logical NOT) to map [] -> true and [...] -> false.

Since the challenge was updated to allow the defaults for decision problems, you could output truthy/falsey inversed with fƑ -> ḟ TIO

@JonathanAllan oh nice, thanks

Nibbles, 14 nibbles (7 bytes)
Program bytes:
d9 87 12 08 3a dd 3b

Human-readable representation:
,|`@128$\ch$P

Attempt This Online!
Outputs zero (falsy) for only-printable-ASCII input, or a positive integer (truthy) for input containing unprintable base-128 digits.
Explanation:
,|`@128$\ch$P   
,               # length of
 |              #   keep
        \   P   #     only unprintable ASCII
         ch$    #   from character representations of
       $        #   input
  `@128         #   as base-128 digits

Note:
Typically, Nibbles programs are written using human-readable (kind-of) tokens representing single-nibble or two-nibble elements.  The Nibbles interpreter should then encode these into the final, runnable program code.
In this case, though, for unknown (to me) reasons, the Nibbles interpreter outputs a warning and refuses to encode this program, even though it runs it correctly.  Nevertheless, it is possible to manually write the 7 program bytes d9 87 12 08 3a dd 3b directly to a file, and run this, as shown.
This is not the normal way to write or run a Nibbles program, but it works.


Python 3, 36 bytes
f=lambda n:-~n%128<33or f(n>>7)*n>>7

Try it online!
Outputs with truthy and falsey swapped
-2 bytes thanks to Themoonisacheese
-2 bytes thanks to squareroot12621
-2 bytes thanks to Albert.Lang
-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

f(n>>7) is shorter by 2 bytes :)

-2 more bytes: f=lambda n:32<-~n%128and(n<128)|f(n>>7)

-2 Swaps True and False.

Using truthy vs falsey (still swapped) you can switch the order and (effectively) use multiplication for the <0> - TIO

@JonathanAllan clever!

R, 44 43 40 bytes
Edit: -3 bytes thanks to pajonk
f=\(x)(x+1)%%128>31&(!(y=x%/%128)||f(y))

Attempt This Online!

-3 bytes by using laziness of ||

@pajonk - Nice, thanks!  I will (try to) remember that...

x86-64 machine code function, 18 bytes
Integer arg in ECX, bool return value in AL (actually zero-extended to RAX).  If I'd used EDI for the arg, this would be compatible with the x86-64 System V calling convention.  As-is, it's Windows x64.
NASM listing trimmed to show hexdump of machine code and source.
                 ; takes a string of ASCII digits packed into a 32-bit integer
                 packedascii_is_printable:
                 .loop:
 8D4101            lea  eax, [rcx+1]   ; wrap 0x7f to 0x80 = -128 if we use a signed compare.  Or to 0 since this is before AND
                             ; 32-bit alternative  mov eax, ecx  (2 bytes) ;  inc eax  (1 byte) before or after AND
 247F              and  al, 0x7F        ; isolate low 7 bits - one ASCII character
 3C21              cmp  al, 0x21        ; increment by one mapped the printable range to 0x21 - 0x7f from the usual 0x20 - 0x7e
 0F9DC0            setge al             ; set return value according to most recent character checked
 7C05              jl   .found_false    ; early out on first false, else keep checking
 C1E907            shr  ecx, 7
 75EF              jnz  .loop           ; leave the loop after processing all the set bits, since our input numbers aren't actually fixed-width in bits.
                 .found_false:
 C3                ret
                         
                 ; return value in AL (zero extended to EAX, actually, since we don't exit the loop until high bits of ECX are clear)

We add 1 and copy the low 7-bit character into AL, and isolate it with AND.  Then check if it's 0x21 to 0x7f, i.e. if the original was 0x20 to 0x7e.  Since every 7-bit value is <= 0x7f, we only have to check the low end of the range, hence adding 1.
This isn't as compact as I'd like, it feels like there should be a way to avoid both a branch and a 3-byte setcc.  Perhaps I could make use 32-bit mode for salc if I can use an unsigned compare. (Undocumented opcode that sets AL according to CF).  I think I can since we cmp after clearing the high bit.

Hey, recently stumbled across hex0 bootstrapping project which has some pretty interesting golfing. Figured you might be interested in it. If you are (and want to code review me a bit) I made a PR.

Can you make 0 return -> ~~invalid~~ valid, then change it sub al, 0x21; jl .found_false; shr ecx, 7; jnz .loop; xor eax, eax; .found_false: ret? Think that saves a byte.

Actually better xchg eax, ecx instead of xor

Go, 75 68 bytes
func f(n int)bool{for k:=n;k>0;k>>=7{if -^k%128<33{n=0}}
return n>0}

Attempt This Online!
Based on @Jitse's answer.
Does not swap true and false.

-7 bytes by @ovs, return the first return with n=0, forcing the final return to false.


I think you can replace the first return with n=0

APL+WIN, 36 bytes
Prompts for integer. Index origin=0. 1=true, 0=false
(+/v∊32+⍳95)=⍴v←((⌈128⍟2⌈n)⍴128)⊤n←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

JavaScript (Node.js), 30 bytes
f=n=>-~n%128<33?n<!!n:f(n/128)

Try it online!
Same length with Arnauld but somehow nicer output
JavaScript (Node.js), 26 bytes
f=n=>-~n%128<33?!n:f(n>>7)

Try it online!
Worse input

MATL, 10 9 bytes
7W_YA6Y2m

Outputs a vector of ones (which is truthy) or a vector containing at least a zero (which is falsy) depending on whether the result only uses printable ASCII or not.
Try it online! Or verify all test cases (the code includes test for truthiness/falsihood).
Explanation
      % Implicit input
7W    % 7, base-2 exponentiation: gives 128
_YA   % Convert to base 128
6Y2   % Push ASCII range (predefined literal): ' ':'~'
m     % Ismember (element-wise)
      % Implicit display


Vyxal, 6 bytes
₇τCkQF

Try it Online!
Outputs an empty list for truthy, a non-empty list for falsey.

Bash, 54 44 bytes
-10 bytes by Dominic van Essen and GammaFunction
(($1%128%127>31))&&((($1<128))||$0 $[$1>>7])

Attempt This Online!
54 bytes
Use as a bash script. Takes in number as first argument, returns with 1 for false and 0 for true (bash convention).
ATO link assumes the function is named f because $0 doesn't work in ATO, but the penalty for hardcoding the script name would be a single byte, so the score would be the same.
Turns out this is a port of @Jitse's answer, but i came up with it independently.

45 bytes...?

@DominicvanEssen Nice catch! Would be 46 because of the function name penalty. You can save a couple more bytes with $[ ] instead of $(( )).

nice catch to the both of you!

05AB1E, 9 bytes
žQÇIžyвåP

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
žQ         # Push printable ASCII constant: " !"...|}~"
  Ç        # Convert it to a list of codepoint integers: [32,126]
   I       # Push the input-integer
    žyв    # Convert the (base-10) input to a base-128 list
       å   # Check for each value if it's in the [32,126]-list
        P  # Check if all are truthy
           # (which is output implicitly as result)


K (ngn/k), 24 bytes
f:{&/(a<127),31<a:128\x}

Try it online!

K (ngn/k), 16 bytes
1~&/~32 127'128\


            128\   /decode in base 128
     32 127'       /-1 if <32, 0 if 32<=x<127, 1 if 127<x
  &/~              /all 0?
1~                 /is 1? (since the unit element for & is 9223372036854775807

Try it online!

Charcoal, 11 bytes
⌊⍘Ｎ⭆¹²⁸№γ℅ι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Actually outputs 1 or 0 for once. Explanation:
  Ｎ         Input as a number
 ⍘          Convert to custom string base
    ¹²⁸     Literal integer `128`
   ⭆        Map over implicit range and join
       №    Count of
          ι Current value
         ℅  Convert to Unicode
        γ   In printable ASCII
⌊           Take the minimum
            Implicitly print

Would have been 10 bytes if the output for 0 was truthy as @xnor suggests:
⬤↨Ｎ¹²⁸№γ℅ι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. 1 if all of the characters a printable ASCII, nothing if not. Explanation:
  Ｎ         Input as a number
 ↨          Converted to base
   ¹²⁸      Literal integer `128`
⬤           All values satisfy
      №     Count of
         ι  Current value
        ℅   Convert to Unicode
       γ    In printable ASCII
            Implicitly print


Java, 64 bytes
x->{if(x==0)x=1;while(x%128!=127&&x%128>31){x>>=7;}return x==0;}


55 bytes

C (gcc), 54
Non recursive solution:
f(n,a){a=1;for(n=n?:1;n&&(a=isprint(n&127));n>>=7);a;}

Try it online!
C (gcc), 55
Recursive solution is 1 byte longer:
g(n){n=n?isprint(n&127)?g(n>>=7):0:1;}f(n){n=n?g(n):0;}

Try it online!

Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 41 36 bytes
Returns 0 for false and a non-zero integer for true.
{$_*?(127>.polymod(128 xx*).all>31)}

Attempt This Online!

C (gcc), 35 34 bytes
f(n){while(n&&95-~n%128>>7)n>>=7;}

Try it online!

@ceilingcat Nice one! In my mind negative inputs to % are firmly in the "let's just pretend that it's not allowed and not worry about how it works" category...

Japt -!, 9 bytes
;s#òd)kE

Try it
;s#òd)kE     :Implicit input of integer
 s            :Convert to string in base
  #          :  127 (note the unprintable after the #)
    ò         :  Range [0,127]
     d        :    Character at each codepoint
      )       :End base conversion
       k      :Remove characters in
;       E     :  ASCII
              :Implicit output of logical NOT of resulting string


Desmos, 84105 bytes
Thanks to Aiden Chow for removing B(x) and 21 bytes
k=128
f(n)=\left\{31<mod(floor(n/k^{[0...floor(log_k(n+0^n))]}),k)<k-1,0\right\}.min

Try it on Desmos (with test cases)

Explanation
f(x) checks each character's printability, returning 1 for printable text and 0 for unprintable text.

If you are pasting this in to try yourself, you may need to "activate" the f(n) equation by focusing (clicking) on it and pressing either the left or right arrow key on your keyboard or the built-in Desmos keyboard. This is likely because I don't use the backslashes in \join, \floor, \mod etc. (not sure how Desmos breaks when this happens though), so this solution is susceptible to Desmos bugfixes breaking my code I guess

Or you can paste in the f(n) line individually because that works I guess

78 bytes

Shortest I could get your recursive function method is 82 bytes.

That doesn't seem to work on my end. I'm on Microsoft Edge if you want to try to replicate that | UPDATE: pasting in \{\} doesn't do anything for me (maybe you are on a different browser) and I can't be bothered to check non-Edge browsers right now, will come back to this later (@remind me pls)

Also, I explained the \join \floor \mod thing, which got me 78+11-5=84 bytes (do you not use that? Is it an Edge-only bug? Is it intended by Desmos?)

It should be browser-independent. Try to paste in k=128 on the first line, then while the cursor is still on the first line, paste in ¶f(n)=\{31<\mod(\floor(n/k^{[0...\floor(\log_k(n+0^n))]}),k)<127,0\}.\min (where ¶ indicates a newline)

Note that the backslash before each function name is required or else Desmos does not parse the expression correctly; this only happens within piecewise expressions that do not involve \left and \right.

Here is a relevant Desmos code golf tip regarding removing \left and \right from piecewise expressions.

Uiua, 55 bytes (UTF-8), 30 chars
c ← 128
/↧∊:+32⇡95⌊◿c÷ⁿ:c⇡⌈ₙc.

